# Valgrind error and generic list with one allocation per element

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind, generic-programming, pointer-arithmetic

I'm experimenting with linked lists and tried to create a generic doubly linked list which allocates memory only once for each node. It means that the memory for the node and the element the node contains is allocated within same `malloc` invocation.
The list itself is a structure which contains size of a unit (initialized with `sizeof(struct which_is_an_element)`:

```
struct doubly_linked_list
{
    struct dll_node *head, *tail;
    size_t elem_size;
};
```

The node:

```
struct dll_node
{
    struct dll_node *next, *prev;
    void *elem;
};
```

Now, when I try to insert element and initialize it:

```
static struct dll_node * new_node(
        struct doubly_linked_list *l, 
        void *elem)
{
    struct dll_node *n = malloc (
        sizeof(struct dll_node) + l->elem_size);

    // This line throws valgrind error
    memcpy(n + sizeof(struct dll_node), elem, l->elem_size); 

    n->prev = n->next = NULL;
    n->elem = n + sizeof(struct dll_node);
    return n;
}
```

I get a valgrind error:

> Invalid write of size 8
>   at 0x4C3217B: memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14   (vg_replace_strmem.c:1022)
>   by 0x400705: new_node (doubly_linked_list.c:20)
>   by 0x400768: dl_list_insert_at_tail   (doubly_linked_list.c:30)
>   by 0x40093F: main (main.c:24)
>   Address 0x5204280 is 480 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,112 in arena "client"

1. Does really `memcpy` write inside unallocated block as the size of the allocated memory is equal to `sizeof(struct which_is_an_element) + sizeof(dll_node)`?
2. Are those issues caused by valgrind thinking the allocated memory has size = `sizeof(struct dll_node)` because of the type of the pointer called `n` inside `new_node` function which points to the data?
3. Is this approach good? Can I allocate the memory once for each element or should I allocate memory for the node and the element separately?
4. If this approach is good then how could I get rid of this valgrind error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does really `memcpy` write inside unallocated block as the size of the allocated memory is equal to `sizeof(struct which_is_an_element) + sizeof(dll_node)`?

Yes.

Doing `memcpy(n + sizeof(struct dll_node), ...` points `sizeof(struct dll_node) * sizeof *n` (equal to `sizeof(struct dll_node) * sizeof(struct dll_node)`) bytes beyond where `n` points to.

You probably want to just "seek" `sizeof(struct dll_node)` bytes.

Do to so change your code to be:

```
memcpy((char*)n + sizeof(struct dll_node), ...
```

or, as `n` *is* a pointer to  `struct dll_node`, just do

```
memcpy(n + 1, ...
```

to get beyond a `struct dll_node`.

Comment: Thank you very much. For clarification the line `n->elem = n + sizeof(struct dll_node);` also contains an error. It should be: `n->elem = n + 1`.